# render array of nested components in react

Tags: reactjs

The project I'm currently working on is basically the creation of a questionnaire, where you can have multiple questions and multiple answers for each of them. 
Clicking on a button (one to add a new answer, and one to add a new question), an input text is added in the page.

This I what I expect:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/loDA6.png

This is what happens: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0j37.png

Codepen example: https://codepen.io/Sirius094/pen/aMdzeo

This is the code. I cut it some parts. Belowe there are my thoughts...

```
class FormQuiz extends React.Component<Props, State> {
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            children: [],
            childrenAnswer: [],
            count: this.props.initialValues.question.length,
            prevState: 0,
            countAnswers: 0
        };
    }



    render() {

       return (
            <div>
              <div id="box-container">
               {this.state.children.map((input: any) => { return input; })}
              </div>

                <button type="button" onClick={() => {this.addQuestionForm();}}>
                    Add Question
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    }

    addQuestionForm() {
        var result = this.state.children;

        result.push(
            <div>
                <button type="button" onClick={() => 
                  this.addAnswer();
                 }}>
                    Add Answer
                </button>

                <FormikFieldWrapper
                    name={"question[" + 
                    this.state.count + "].text"}
                    value=""
                    type="text"
                />
            </div>
        );

        this.setState({
            children: result,
            prevState: this.state.count,
            count: this.state.count + 1
        });
    }

    addAnswer() {
        var result = this.state.children;

        result.push(
            <div>
                <FormikFieldWrapper
                    name={
                        "question[" +
                        this.state.prevState +
                        "].answers[" +
                        this.state.countAnswers +
                        "].text"
                    }
                    value=""
                    type="text"
                />
            </div>
        );

        this.setState({
            children: result,
            countAnswers: this.state.countAnswers + 1
        });
    }
}
```

So basically the methods addQuestionForm() and addAnswer() use the array children to append the input text, which I iterate in the render method with map().
I think the problem is that the array children is literally a mess full of inputs and react doesn't know where render each of them correctly. Or am I totally wrong? I tried to create a separate array for the answer (childAnswer) and then used two methods map() one inside the other, but I failed. I'm sure I'm missing something really obvious...

Comment: Issue is how your DOM is structured. You're essentially snapshotting the tree then appending after the fact. Also I'd highly recommend against keep track of actual nodes... When I was first learning React, I found it helpful to try breaking down the code into more digestible pieces. Based on what you've provided, it seems you want to have a Form. Your Form consist of Questions. Questions have Answers. My recommendation would be to set it up in that manner. Here's an example using your source - https://codepen.io/dirtyd77/pen/MxKwzW  Hope this helps and let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The good thing about React is that it allows you to think in declarative data structures and transformations on them. If you have questions, and each question may have many answers, it seems like a collection where each item contains a collection would make sense. Something like this:

```
[
  {
    question: "Question A",
    answers: []
  },
  {
    question: "Question B",
    answers: []
  }
];
```

Adding a new question would then result in this:

```
[
  {
    question: "Question A",
    answers: []
  },
  {
    question: "Question B",
    answers: []
  },
  {
    question: "Question C",
    answers: []
  }
];
```

while adding an answer to, say, question A, in this:

```
[
  {
    question: "Question A",
    answers: ["Answer A"]
  },
  {
    question: "Question B",
    answers: []
  }
];
```

Having this data structure, you can then map through all items. In this case, let's assume that we don't need recursion as we are completely certain that there will be only two levels of nested collections. The code would then go like this:

```
class FormQuiz extends React.Component {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    this.state = {
      questions: [
        {
          question: "Question A",
          answers: ["Answer A"]
        },
        {
          question: "Question B",
          answers: []
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.questions.map(({ question, answers }) => (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div>
          <label>{question}</label>
          <input type="text" value={question} />
        </div>
        {answers.map(answer => (
          <div>
            <label>{answer}</label>
            <input type="text" value={answer} />
          </div>
        ))}
      </React.Fragment>
    ));
  }
}
```

Given this structure, you can now think of eliminating the missing key prop issue, actually changing values via component state, etc. For example, adding a new (empty) answer would be a function that only requires one argument: index (or better, globally unique ID) of the target question. Like this:

```
class FormQuiz extends React.Component {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    this.state = {
      questions: [
        {
          question: "Question A",
          answers: ["Answer A"]
        },
        {
          question: "Question B",
          answers: []
        }
      ]
    };
    this.appendAnswer = this.appendAnswer.bind(this);
  }

  appendEmptyAnswer(targetQuestionIndex) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      questions: prevState.questions.map((question, index) =>
        targetQuestionIndex !== index
          ? question
          : { ...question, answers: [...question.answers, ""] } // <- just add an empty string as the new answer
      )
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.questions.map(({ question, answers }, index) => (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div>
          <label>{question}</label>
          <input type="text" value={question} />
          <button onClick={() => this.appendEmptyAnswer(index)}>
            Add answer
          </button>
        </div>
        {answers.map(answer => (
          <div>
            <label>{answer}</label>
            <input type="text" value={answer} />
          </div>
        ))}
      </React.Fragment>
    ));
  }
}
```

And in a similar fashion with adding the questions.

Once you have it working, you may think of optimizing the code for maintainability a little bit.

Also, remember that if you have a stateful component that does not produce side-effects, hooks could help make the code a bit more readable, like

```
const appendEmptyAnswer = (questions, targetQuestionIndex) =>
  questions.map((question, index) =>
    targetQuestionIndex !== index
      ? question
      : { ...question, answers: [...question.answers, ""] }
  );

const FormQuiz = () => {
  const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([
    {
      question: "Question A",
      answers: ["Answer A"]
    },
    {
      question: "Question B",
      answers: []
    }
  ]);

  return questions.map(({ question, answers }, index) => (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>
        <label>{question}</label>
        <input type="text" value={question} />
        <button
          onClick={() => setQuestions(appendEmptyAnswer(questions, index))}
        >
          Add answer
        </button>
      </div>
      {answers.map(answer => (
        <div>
          <label>{answer}</label>
          <input type="text" value={answer} />
        </div>
      ))}
    </React.Fragment>
  ));
};
```

Good luck!

Comment: Wow thanks you a lot!! Now works just fine :) I'm going to analyze more deeply the code because I'm sure I will run into this same issue in the future lol

Answer (score 0):

As with @Fleischpfanzerl's answer, I suggest you to simplify the way you store questions and answers. In my example you store both questions and answers in one array, and render the list when a new entity is added -- it is quite more obvious for human understanding and lets (IMHO) avoid possible problems and bugs which could happen when you use different arrays to store linked data:

```
class Button extends React.Component {
  state = {
    questions: [],
  };

  renderQuestions() {
    return this.state.questions.map((question, questionId) => (
      <div>
        <div>
          <label>Question #{question.id}</label>
          <input type="text" />
          <button type="button" onClick={() => {this.addAnswer(questionId)}}>
            Add Answer 
          </button>
        </div>
        <div>
          {this.renderAnswers(questionId)}
        </div>
      </div>
    ));
  }

  renderAnswers(questionId) {
    return this.state.questions[questionId].answers.map((answer) => (
      <div>
        <label>Answer #{answer.id}</label>
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
    ));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div id="box-container">
          {this.renderQuestions()}
        </div>
        <br/>
        <button type="button" onClick={() => {this.addQuestionForm()}}>
          Add Question
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }


  addQuestionForm() {
    const { questions } = this.state;

    this.setState({
      questions: [
        ...questions,
        {
          id: questions.length,
          answers: [],
        },
      ],
    });
  }

  addAnswer(questionId) {
    const questionsCloned = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.questions));

    questionsCloned[questionId].answers.push({
      id: questionsCloned[questionId].answers.length,
      text: "",
    });

    this.setState({
      questions: questionsCloned,
    });
  }
}

React.render(<Button />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

So, the structure of array is something like this:

```
questions: [
  {
    id: 1,
    answers: [
      {
        id: 1,
      },
      {
        id: 2,
      },
    },
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    answers: [
      {
        id: 1,
      },
      {
        id: 2,
      },
      {
        id: 3,
      },
    },
  },
  ...
]
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GeoJPG?editors=1011

Comment: Thanks for the codepen, it was very helpful to understand quickly what I was doing wrong :) best regards